# Why am i not writing to my database

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

Here is my code what am i doing wrong. I have a form submit the name and beername info connect to mydatabase. I test my connect my connection with no errors. i test to make sure that the vars are defined. last i try to write to my database but i get this error:

> Warning: mysqli::query() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given
>   in /home/zacgre4/zachjgreen.dreamhosters.com/Homebrew/contact.php on
>   line 15.

my code is:

```
if(isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["beername"])){
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $beername = $_POST["beername"];
    $host="admin.zachjgreen.dreamhosters.com";
    $un="musicchild";
    $pw="xxxxxxxx";
    $dbn="adminzjg";
    $db=new mysqli($host, $un, $pw, $dbn);
    if($db->connect_errno > 0){
        echo "Failed " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    echo $name; 
    echo $beername;
    $db->query($con, "INSERT INTO Beers VALUE ($name, $beername)"); //this is line 15
}
```

Comment: Unless you're using prepared statements.... which you should be in 2014, then you need to quote string values in SQL queries

Comment: dont you need to escape variables in a query?

Comment: Its `$object->query($querystring)`, or non-OO `mysqli_query($con,$querystring)`, [not a combination](http://nl3.php.net/mysqli_query). And you don't quote or escape your strings BTW, which is the next error you'll encounter. Please go for [prepared statements](http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php).

Comment: May I suggest to read my post? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25174599/secure-my-php-code-for-login-registration-codes/25174702#25174702

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need quotes around the variables but that is not safe for sql injection but also error prone, you should prepare that query:

```
 if(isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["beername"])){
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $beername = $_POST["beername"];

    //connection
    $host="admin.zachjgreen.dreamhosters.com";
    $un="musicchild";
    $pw="xxxxxxxx";
    $dbn="adminzjg";


    $db = new mysqli($host, $un, $pw, $dbn);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }


    /* create a prepared statement */
    if ($stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO Beers VALUES (?, ?)")) {

        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $name, $beername);
        $stmt->execute();

        printf ("New Record has id %d.\n", $db->insert_id);


        $stmt->close();
    }

    /* close connection */
    $db->close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it connects without errors, then the problem is with the query.
You need to specify which columns to insert. It should look something like

```
"INSERT INTO Beers (name, beer_name) VALUES ($name, $beername)"
```

where `name` and `beer_name` are columns in your table

You can echo out the query to see what it looks like. then copy it into mysql console, ie:

```
echo "INSERT INTO Beers VALUE ($name, $beername)"
```

also, this script very unsafe, but that's outside the scope of your question.